# down sampling in r for regression (NOT classification)

Tags: r, regression

At the moment I am using simply:

```
down_sample_size = 3000
train <- train[sample(nrow(train), down_sample_size),]
```

to down-sample my training data to make my model fitting faster (in the context of hyper parameters search and CV - above is simplified). Are there better ways of doing this? In the context of classification, for example, class priors and stratification have to be taking into account. However, maybe the above is acceptable for regression? Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at the downSample function in caret, also https://topepo.github.io/caret/subsampling-for-class-imbalances.html

Comment: I am aware of this but it is for classification. If not, please correct me. Thanks.

Comment: Random sampling is the usual procedure. Anything else may be biased. I voted to migrate this to stats.stackoverflow, in case there are special cases where different procedures are appropriate.

Comment: @dww I posted this here as the responsiveness and kindness is generally higher (-:

Comment: Sure, but although you phrased this as a programming question, it is really a question about the approriate statistical method to use.  The expertise and relevance for such is over on cross-validated.  Its also off-topic for here because it asks to recommend a tool or function to use.

Answer (score 0):

This seems perfectly acceptable unless you have clusters or any other viable reason to sample non-randomly. I've done something similar hundreds of times for linear regression.

Comment: Why the down-vote? If you down-voted - at least comment why!